# What are Lua's Introspection features?

Tags: lua, introspection

What are Lua's introspection features? I know that you can query the type of a variable at runtime using `type(var)` and that the debug package provides some features for inspecting the environment, but it is not clear what that gives me.

What other introspection features are in Lua? Any good resources?

Comment: In Lua, only *values* have types. Variables can hold values of any type at any time.

Comment: Static analysis can give the scope of a variable, the fields from a table constructor, the type of value in a variable immediately after assignment from a literal, .... Is that what you are interested in?

Comment: @lhf Great point! That never occurred to me before. I guess I'm looking for introspection functionality for both variables and values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua values can have 7 types: nil, boolean, number, string, function, userdata, thread, and table. You can get the type of a value using the [`type`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-type) function from the standard library.

If you are working with tables, you can iterate over its keys using the [`pairs`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-pairs) function.

Finally, values in Lua can have metatables and this is often used in to program in an object oriented style. You can get a value's metatable using the [`getmetatable`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-getmetatable) function.

Comment: And, `debug.getinfo` can be used for function values.

Answer (score 2):

You actually have to use the built-in function `type()` to get a variable's type at run time

```
t = 'asdf'
print(type(t))
```

for example. As far as introspection, the debug library is pretty much it for vanilla Lua. The best place to begin poking around would be in the [reference manual for the debug library](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.10).

Comment: I edited the original question to fix the syntax problem with `type()`. Thanks!